# Verifying sheaf base axiom $2$ on $\operatorname{Spec} A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $\operatorname{Spec} A$ be the spectrum of $A$ with its Zariski topology. A base for this topology is given by distinguished opens $U_f$. I am trying to verify that the presheaf on the base $U_f\mapsto A_f$ (the localization of $A$ by the multiplicative closure of $\{f\}$) satisfies the sheaf on a base axioms. I asked a question about sheaf axiom $1$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805742/defining-the-structure-sheaf-on-an-affine-scheme/4805810#4805810), but I am now confused about to verify the second axiom.

My attempt is modeled off of Vakil's proof in the Geometry of schemes when $U=\operatorname{Spec} A$. Let $U_g$ be a distinguished open covered by (finitely many) $U_{f_i}$, and let $s_i\in A_{f_i}$ be sections which agree on overlaps. Now for some large enough $K$,
we can regard $f_i^Ks_i$ as an element of $A$, $A_g$, or $A$, as if:
$$s_i=\frac{a_i}{f_i^{n_i}}$$
then when $K\geq a_i$ we have that:
$$f_i^Ks_i=\frac{f_i^{K-n_i}a_i}{1}$$
so the element $f_i^{K-n_i}$ in $A$, and the element $f_i^{K-n_i}/1$ in $A_g$ both map to $f_i^Ks_i$ in $A_f$. Now since $s_i$ and $s_j$ agree on overlaps, we have that $(f_if_j)^Ks_i$ and $(f_if_j)^Ks_j$ agree on overlaps, and taking $(f_if_j)^Ks_i$ and $(f_if_j)^Ks_j$ as elements of a ring, we have that for some larger $K$:
$$(f_if_j)^Ks_j=(f_if_j)^Ks_i$$
We define $h_i\in A_g$ by taking $f_i^Ks_i$ as an element of $A_g$ and setting $h_i=f_i^Ks_i$. Then we have that:
$$f_j^Kh_i=f_i^Kh_i$$
Now note that we for some $m$ we have that:
$$g^m=\sum_{i}e_if_i^K$$
where $e_i\in A$. So we define the section of $U_g$, $s$ by:
$$s=\sum_ie_ih_i$$
We would like this to agree on overlaps, but note that $s$ has the form $a/1$ for some $a\in A$, hence:
$$s|_{U_j}= \frac{\sum_ie_ih_i}{1}$$
However, we have that as elements of $A$:
$$f_j^Ks=\sum_i f_j^Ke_ih_i=\sum_ie_if_i^Kh_j=g^mh_j=g^mf_j^Ks_j$$

From here I am stuck, I have no idea what this $g^m$ factor is doing here or how to get it as some power of $f_j$ on both sides. In Vakil's proof, he gets $g^m=1$ because $A_g=A$, so it just works out. I suspect there is something I am misunderstanding about the proof, but my attempts to brute force it have left me in a barrage of indices that is borderline unreadable...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use `$\operatorname{Spec}$` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ - it produces better spacing than your previous use of \text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out I think.

Let $U_g$ be a distinguished open and $U_{f_i}$ a finite open cover. Let $s_i\in A_{f_i}$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
    \theta^i_{ij}(s_i)=\theta^j_{ij}(s_j)
  \end{align*}$$
Set:
$$\begin{align*}
    s_i=\frac{a_i}{f_i^{l_i}}
  \end{align*}$$
and note that since $U_{f_if_j}\subset U_{f_i}, U_{f_j}$ we have that:
$$\begin{align*}
    (f_if_j)^{k^i_{ij}}= b_{ij}^i f_i\qquad \text{and}\qquad (f_if_j)^{k^j_{ij}}= b_{ij}^j f_j
  \end{align*}$$
However, take $k^i_{ij}=k^j_{ij}=1$, then we have that $b^i_{ij}=f_j$, and $b^j_{ij}=f_i$.
It follows that:
$$\begin{align*}
    \theta^i_{ij}(s_i)=\frac{a_i\cdot f_j^{l_i}}{(f_if_j)^{l_i}}=
    \frac{a_j\cdot f_i^{l_j}}{(f_if_j)^{ l_j}}=\theta^j_{ij}(s_j)
  \end{align*}$$
so there exists some $K$ such that for all $i,j$:
$$\begin{align*}
    (f_if_j)^K\cdot\left((f_if_j)^{ l_j}\cdot a_i\cdot f_j^{l_i} -
    (f_if_j)^{l_i}\cdot a_j\cdot f_i^{l_j}\right)=0
  \end{align*}$$
multiply by $f_i^{l_i}f_j^{l_j}$ to obtain:
$$\begin{align*}
    (f_if_j)^{K}\left( a_i\cdot f_j^{l_j} -
     a_j\cdot f_i^{l_i}\right)=0
  \end{align*}$$
where $K=K+l_i+l_j$. Set $K$ to be large enough so that this expression holds for all
$i$ and $j$, and define:
$$\begin{align*}
    h_i=a_i f_i^{K}
  \end{align*}$$
Then note that for some $M$:
$$\begin{align*}
    g^M=\sum_{i}e_i f_i^{K}
  \end{align*}$$
so set:
$$ \begin{align*}
    s=\sum_i \frac{e_i h_i}{g^M}
  \end{align*}$$
and note that we have $f^{n_j}_j=bg$ for some $b$ and $n_j$. The restriction is then:
$$\begin{align*}
    s|_{U_j}=\sum_i\frac{e_i \cdot h_i b^{M}}{f^{n_j M}}
  \end{align*}$$
We claim this equal to $s_j$; indeed we have that:
$$\begin{align*}
    f^{K}_j\left(\sum_i{e_i \cdot h_i\cdot  b}\cdot f^{l_i}_j-a_j\cdot f^{n_j M} \right) 
  \end{align*}$$
Examine the first term:
$$ \begin{align*}
    \sum_i{e_i \cdot h_i\cdot  b^M}\cdot f^{K}_j\cdot f^{l_i}_i=&
    \sum_i{e_i \cdot f_i^{K}\cdot a_i \cdot b}\cdot f^{K}_j\cdot f^{l_i}_i
  \end{align*}$$
For each term we have that $f_i^Kf_j^Kf_i^{l_i}a_i=f_i^Kf_j^K f_j^{l_j}a_j$, hence:
$$\begin{align*}
    \sum_i{e_i \cdot h_i\cdot  b^M}\cdot f^{K}_j\cdot f^{l_i}_i=&(f_j^{l_j}f_j^Ka_jb^M)\sum_i f_i^Ke_i\\
    =&(f_j^{l_j}f_j^Ka_jb^M)\cdot g^M\\
    =&f_j^K\left(f_j^{l_j}a_j f^{n_jM}\right)
  \end{align*}$$
implying the claim.